# Passing value of date variable to pipeline not working

Tags: json, azure, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps

How can I pass a start or end date variable value in my Logic app for my DevOps pipeline without changing the timeformat? When I pass the value with "[value]" or ["value"] my Logic App wont recognize it as a string and won't pass any other variable values after that in the body.

Error when passing the value with "[value]"

```
│ Error: expected "time_period.0.end_date" to be a valid RFC3339 date, got "[2022-05-01T08:05:00.000Z]": parsing time "[2022-05-01T08:05:00.000Z]" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "[2022-05-01T08:05:00.000Z]" as "2006"
│ 
│   with azurerm_consumption_budget_resource_group.management,
│   on costmanagement.tf line 33, in resource "azurerm_consumption_budget_resource_group" "management":
│   33:     end_date   = var.end_date
```

If I pass the value with ["value"] it doesn't work at all

My Question now is: How can I pass the value without so it arrives with "date" on my pipeline.
[DevOps Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB51i.png)

Comment: Can you please provide information about the expression/flow for the specific action that you’re having the issue with? Right now, we’re flying a little blind.

Comment: Im receiving user/order data from a platform to deploy a personal subscription with some basic resources. I then send the data from my Logic App do DevOps and then trigger a YAML Pipeline where I'm filling my values into the variables. Two of the values are start and end date which are needed for a Budget to monitor the deployed subsciprtion. Back to the specific Problem. The Body I'm sending from my Logic App to DevOps contains all values (initialize variables). A part of the Body you can see in the attachement

Comment: It’s still not possible to answer your question. Can you show us how the date that it’s angry about is derived? Is it in a variable? If so how does that come about? An expression? From somewhere else? Is there JSON if it comes from somewhere else? I hope my request makes sense.

Comment: The Data I'm sending from my Logic App is "[2022-05-01T08:05:00.000Z]" and it needs to be like that: "2022-05-01T08:05:00.000Z". If I'm sending the data with "value" it gets parsed and then changed into the wrong timeformat which Terraform doesnt like for the resource. 
The variable shortName would be sent this way:
 "shortName": {
      "isSecret:": false,
      "value": "LR"
    }
Hope it helps.

Comment: No, add all of the details that answer my questions to your question.  We need to see the specifics in the flow to help.